# recursively looping through each value in deps

Tags: python

I am having difficulty looping through each value in deps..currently am able to loop only once.i have the expected output below..can anyone provide inputs on how to change to loop to get the expected output below?

```
'''
EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
external_dep = {
    '253036': ['12345','34567'],
    '12345': [],
    '34567': ['99999']
    '99999': []
    }
'''
def  findexternaldep(num):
    if num == '253036':
        output =['12345','34567']
    if num == '12345':
        output = []
    if num == '34567':
        output = ['99999']
    if num == '99999':
        output = []
    return output

master_gerrit = ["253036"]
external_dep={}
for num in master_gerrit:
    deps=findexternaldep(num)
    #print deps
    external_dep[num] = deps
    #loop should be repeated for each value in the list deps
print external_dep
```

Comment: Is it really a dictionary or JSON object?

Comment: @Makoto - everything is a dictionary,no JSON involved here.

Comment: If none of the `if` statements match, then `output` is returned on the last line, but `output` is never defined on any non-if statement!

Comment: @Hooked - above is one case which I created for the recursive problem I have

Comment: @user2125827: The recursive problem being that there is no recursion. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no recursion. Instead of a loop you need a function that you call recursively. Something like this:

```
external_dep={}
def handle_gerrit(num, external_dep):
    deps=findexternaldep(num)
    external_dep[num] = deps
    for num in deps:
        handle_gerrit(num, external_dep)

handle_gerrit("253036", external_dep)
print external_dep
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs..is there a way we can add smartness to this script meaning..for gerrits that already handled..it should not handle again otherwise the script is going to an infinite loop

Comment: @user2125827: Yes, sure, just check if it's already in external_deps before handling it.